# need to print only certain keys from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

i need to print only these keys from dictionary but not sure how to  do it

keys that needs to be printed:

BAAAAAART!
Eat My Shorts!
d'oh!

```
def print_values_of(dictionary, keys):
    for k in dictionary:
        print(dictionary[k])

simpson_catch_phrases = {"lisa": "BAAAAAART!", 
                    "bart": "Eat My Shorts!", 
                    "marge": "Mmm~mmmmm", 
                    "homer": "d'oh", 
                    "maggie": " (Pacifier Suck)"
                    }
print_values_of(simpson_catch_phrases, "lisa")
```

Comment: 3 `print` statements?  And how does `print_values_of` relate to your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_values_of(dictionary, keys):
    for k in keys:
        print(dictionary[k])

simpson_catch_phrases = {"lisa": "BAAAAAART!", 
                    "bart": "Eat My Shorts!", 
                    "marge": "Mmm~mmmmm", 
                    "homer": "d'oh", 
                    "maggie": " (Pacifier Suck)"
                    }
print_values_of(simpson_catch_phrases, ["lisa","bart","homer"])
```

[image]

Comment: An answer without explanation values nothing

Comment: question is not very clear...i could just figure what output he needed. so thats about it

Comment: thanks tried that still prints out all the items in dictionary

Comment: no it doesnt.. the code i posted is different...delete all your code and paste this. you are very impatient